# Rails shows error "uninitialized constant URI::Generic"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

I'm using rails 5.2.3 with apache2 when I run the development server it shows no error but when I deploy it with passenger and apache2 server it shows this error

```
Error: uninitialized constant URI::Generic,
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

add the first of file (config/application.rb) you can add this line

```
require 'uri'
```

Comment: Do you know this isn't automatically required?

Comment: This also works in Rails 6.0.2.2 (ruby-2.5.0) after creating a new application with `$ rails new blog` and the step `rails  webpacker:install` throws this issue (`Error: uninitialized constant URI::Generic,`). After implementing this fix, re-running the `rails  webpacker:install` command will succeed.